# Do Firestore transactions only retry automatically in contention cases?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Do Firestore transactions automatically retry *only* in contention cases (when changes are made to the underlying documents during the transaction itself)? Or will Firestore automatically retry transactions for other error cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They retry only on contention.  If there is another problem with the write (for example, violated security rule, rate limits, document size limit), it will not be retried.

Comment: I am getting `Error: 10` ABORTED - too much contention... is the built in retry itself limited?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Yes, it will retry a limited number of times.